# Set recyclerview above alignParentBottom layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `recyclerview` and a `button` that is `alignParentBottom`. The view looks fine except that my last row of item for `recyclerview` is blocked by button as it seems that my `recyclerview` is "*behind*" the button and *not* above the button. How can I fix this?

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white_three"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/orderList"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/errorLoadingText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
            android:gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white_three"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/paymentButtonTop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="43dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_radius_toggle_confirm"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="75dp"
            android:text="@string/prepayment"
            android:textColor="@color/warm_grey_two"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/paymentButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="43dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_radius_toggle_confirm"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:textColor="@color/warm_grey_two"
            android:text="@string/prepayment"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:gravity="center" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your parent layout to **Linear Layout**. This will give desired result.

Xml file will be like this:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white_three"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/orderList"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/errorLoadingText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
            android:gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white_three"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/paymentButtonTop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="43dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_radius_toggle_confirm"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="75dp"
            android:text="@string/prepayment"
            android:textColor="@color/warm_grey_two"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/paymentButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="43dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_radius_toggle_confirm"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:textColor="@color/warm_grey_two"
            android:text="@string/prepayment"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:gravity="center" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Although it is not good practice to have `LinearLayout` inside of `RelativeLayout` duo performance issues, you can achieve what you want by setting attribute `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` on bottom LinearLayout and by setting `android:layout_above="@+id/idOfBottomLinearLayout"` on top `LinearLayout`.

In code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white_three"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/orderList"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/errorLoadingText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
            android:gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id = "@+id/bottomLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white_three"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/paymentButtonTop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="43dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_radius_toggle_confirm"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="75dp"
            android:text="@string/prepayment"
            android:textColor="@color/warm_grey_two"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/paymentButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="43dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_radius_toggle_confirm"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:textColor="@color/warm_grey_two"
            android:text="@string/prepayment"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:gravity="center" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to move first `Linear Layout` down. 
Just switch two linear layouts.

Comment: Hmm.. tried and the button disappears, it's hidden behind instead now